# A basic doubt on uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I can prove formally that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,\frac{1}{1000})$, but uniformly continuous in $(\frac{1}{1000},1)$. But don't understand it intuitively. Is it because of the point 0 in the first case. Another point, it looks like uniform continuity does not imply uniform growth rate. In the second example (i.e $(\frac{1}{1000},1)$)near to left end point the function increases rapidly, but near to the right end point the increase is not that much. What is uniform then ?

Comment: "What is uniform then?" The derivative is uniformly bounded by $2\cdot10^9$ on $(1/1000,1)$ hence $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant2\cdot10^9|x-y|$ uniformly on this interval.

Comment: Suppose a function is not differentiable but uniformly continuous. Then what is uniform

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following : If $f$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ where $(a, b)$ is bounded open interval in $\mathbb R$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a, b)$ iff $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a+} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow b-}f(x)$ both exist finitely.

Now because of this $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(\frac{1}{1000}, 1)$ but not in $(0, \frac{1}{1000})$ because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0+} f(x)$ does not exist finitely.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the definitions of Continuity and Uniform Continuity .

A function $f$ is continuous in an interval $I$ if for every $x \in I$ , given any $\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists \delta(\epsilon,x) >0$ such that $\forall y \in I$ satisfying $|x-y|<\delta(\epsilon,x) \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ .

On the other hand for Uniform Continuity , we have, a function $f$ is uniformly continuous in an interval $I$ if for every $x \in I$ , given any $\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists \delta(\epsilon) >0$ such that $\forall y \in I$ satisfying $|x-y|<\delta(\epsilon) \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ .

So in case of Continuity, $\delta = \delta(\epsilon,x)$ i.e. function of both $\epsilon$ and your choice of $x$ .

But , in case of Uniform Continuity,$\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ i.e. only depends on $\epsilon$. In other words, you can find a $\delta$ suitably chosen according to the choice of $\epsilon$ so that it will work for $\forall x \in I$ .

Now, it's easy to work with your problem. Around $0$ , you'll fail to find a $\delta$ that will work for all the desired points.

In that sense, choice of $\delta$ for the entire $I$ is uniform in the latter case.